# set right permission to get connection ip for a user mapped to login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, security

I have a problem with properly settings the rights permissions for my user to get access to connections ips.

I know that, to get the conn ip I must set the VIEW SERVER STATE to the login that I use to connect to db. I know hot to do it and it works ok. The problem is when I want to execute a stored procedure that is executed as other user. This user (mapped to the login with the above permission) doesn't have permission to get the ip. What I have missed?

A script to reproduce:

```
CREATE LOGIN TestLogin WITH PASSWORD=N'TestLogin', 
                                    DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], 
                                    CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, 
                                    CHECK_POLICY=OFF

CREATE USER TestUser FOR LOGIN TestLogin

use master
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO TestLogin
```

With this I can log to the database and execute the query:

```
SELECT client_net_address
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
WHERE Session_id = @@SPID
```

But when I add the procedure I can't execute it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc
WITH EXECUTE AS 'TestUser'
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT client_net_address
    FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
    WHERE Session_id = @@SPID
END

GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::dbo.TestProc TO TestUser
```

All I got is

```
Msg 297, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TestProc, Line 5
The user does not have permission to perform this action.
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with you code. Just make sure that Create Procedure and Grant statements are being executed separately or at least place a GO statement between both.

Answer (score 1):

sys.dm_exec_connections will require the permissions you've stated of `VIEW SERVER STATE`. However, by looking at the code you only ever want to get the IP of the session the user is already in, so there is no need for the over-provisioning. Using `CONNECTIONPROPERTY` will fulfill the same request and NOT require any extra permissions.

I'd make it something as such:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address')
END

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TestProc TO TestUser
```

You can then test:

```
USE YourDatabase
GO

EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'TestLogin'
 EXEC dbo.TestProc
REVERT
```